# insert input from form to database using php and jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

i use a simple uploadscript for uploading some pics to my server and add some information in a database for a galery. the script works fine. all pics are uploaded to the right place and the variables i defined are set in the database. only the input from my form (text from field and area and radiobutton) will not be inserted to mysql.

this is the script i use to start the upload and insert the data into the db.

```
$( "#load" ).submit(function( event ) {

uploadObj.startUpload();  

event.preventDefault();
});
```

here is the form

```
<form id="load" action="">
<p style="color: #05296B;"><b>Galerietitel:</b>
<input class="textbox" type="text" name="gal_title" style="width: 200px; margin-left: 164px;" /></p>
<p style="color: #05296B;"><b>Galerietext:</b></p>
  <p><textarea id="styled" name="gal_text" onfocus="setbg('#FFF9B1');" onblur="setbg('#e5fff3')"  style="resize: none; color: #05296B;" WRAP=SOFT></textarea></p>
 <p style="color: #05296B;"><b>Öffentliche Galerie?:</b>
 <input type="radio" id="publics" name="publics" style="margin-left: 80px;" value="1" checked >  ja
 <input type="radio" id="publics" name="publics" style="margin-left: 25px;" value="0" /> nein
</p>

 <div id="fileuploader">Bilder auswählen</div>

<input type="submit" class="button-link" value="Hoch laden">
</form>
```

and finally the php

```
$gal_title = $_POST['gal_title'];
$gal_text = $_POST['gal_text'];
$publics = $_POST['publics'];
$nickname = "ms";
$test = "marco";
$path2 = date('dmY');
$path3 = mt_rand(1, 999999);
$uploads = $test."_".$path2.$path3;

$output_dir = "galerie/".$uploads."/";
if(isset($_FILES["loadpic"]))
{

mkdir('galerie/'.$uploads.'', 0775);



$ret = array();

$error =$_FILES["loadpic"]["error"];
if(!is_array($_FILES["loadpic"]["name"])) 
{

    $fileName = $_FILES["loadpic"]["name"];
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["loadpic"]["tmp_name"],$output_dir.$fileName);
    $ret[]= $fileName;
}
else 
{
  $fileCount = count($_FILES["loadpic"]["name"]);
  for($i=0; $i < $fileCount; $i++)
  {
    $fileName = $_FILES["loadpic"]["name"][$i];
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["loadpic"]["tmp_name"][$i],$output_dir.$fileName);
    $ret[]= $fileName;

  }

}


$stamp = time();


        $sql = "INSERT INTO
                galery
                (user_id,
                nickname,
                uploads,
                gal_title,
                gal_text,
                publics,
                datum
               )
           VALUES
                ('".mysql_real_escape_string(trim($test))."',
                 '".mysql_real_escape_string(trim($nickname))."',   
                 '".mysql_real_escape_string(trim($uploads))."',
                 '".mysql_real_escape_string(trim($gal_title))."',    
                 '".mysql_real_escape_string(trim($gal_text))."',
                 '".mysql_real_escape_string(trim($publics))."', 
                 '".mysql_real_escape_string(trim($stamp))."'    
                 )";    
                  mysql_query($sql) OR die("<pre>\n".$sql."</pre>\n".mysql_error());
```

'gal_title' , 'gal_text' and 'publics' will not be inserted into the database. so all data from my form. what is wrong?

@Forgest:

here i call the galery_upload.php (the file that all the code contains):

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
var uploadObj = $("#fileuploader").uploadFile({

url:"galery_upload.php",

multiple:true,

autoSubmit:false,

fileName:"loadpic",

formData: {name:"load"},

maxFileSize:20480,

maxFileCount:6,

dynamicFormData: function()

{

var data ={ location:"Germany"}

return data;

},
```

Comment: add method="post" in the form. By Default its GET

Comment: maybe you must add a method type into your form head: `<form id="load" action="" method="POST">`

Answer (score 0):

Your form creation should be a POST as you are getting POST data. Switch your top line of your html from:

```
<form id="load" action="">
```

to:

```
<form id="load" action="" method="POST">
```

This should fix your problem.

Comment: thanks for the qucik response. i added method="post" and 'publics' is inserted into the database. but i get still nothing form title and text.

Comment: unfortunately still nothing. i changed also the default of publics from 0 to 1 in the database. it looks that the data from my form will be completely ignored.

Comment: @Kallmas well you don't seem to be calling the php file anywhere. I mean how is it even getting to the php?

Comment: i putted the url further above in another part of the script. i have added this part in my post to show you how i did it.
i also added the .php to the action of my form with no success.
have i to add the url to my .submit?

Comment: @Kallmas I am not sure what is wrong then. Take a look at this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/runetusi/1/edit?html,output) file and look at the get parameters when you submit (look in url). The title, text, and publics field are all there with no issue. You are not getting the data correctly in PHP it would seem.

Answer (score 0):

i solved it. i had to give the data from my form into

```
var data = $("form :input").serialize();
```

before there was just an example set in my var data +eyes roll+
now all needed data is going to the right place. thanks for all your help.

Comment: damned. i got the data into my database but now i get also each file in its own folder. but what i want is all uploaded files in one folder. has some one an idea what i do wrong now?